# Problem setting parameter Values to equal DataColumn Values

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, datatable

Coding in VB.Net

Hi guys I've got this problem where I'm trying to assign some parameters for a stored procedure with some values that are stored in a data table.  in the code, I can set the parameter values to the data table, and give a column header or index without issue, but when it tries to execute at runtime it bombs out.

the error I get is a variation on "Failed to Convert Parameter Value from a DataColumn to a String" depending on exactly how I try to assign the value.

the data types are all correct elsewhere in the code, so I'm pretty certain that's not the issue, I guess I'm just going about this the wrong way.

my code for this bit is

---

```
Try
ConnectionAttempt.Open()
Try
    With NewYearCommand_Dates
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .CommandText = "DatesINSERT"
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AcademicYear", SqlDbType.VarChar))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@YearStart", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@YearEnd", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term1Start", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term1End", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term2Start", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term2End", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term3Start", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Term3End", SqlDbType.Date))
        .Parameters("@AcademicYear").Value = dates.Columns("AcademicYear")
        .Parameters("@YearStart").Value = dates.Columns("YearStart")
        .Parameters("@YearEnd").Value = dates.Columns("YearEnd")
        .Parameters("@Term1Start").Value = dates.Columns("Term1Start")
        .Parameters("@Term1End").Value = dates.Columns("Term1End")
        .Parameters("@Term2Start").Value = dates.Columns("Term2Start")
        .Parameters("@Term2End").Value = dates.Columns("Term2End")
        .Parameters("@Term3Start").Value = dates.Columns("Term3Start")
        .Parameters("@Term3End").Value = dates.Columns("Term3End")
        .Connection = ConnectionAttempt
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
        .Dispose()
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

---

other things I've tried to get this to work are all variations on the .Value=dates bit, such as

.Value=dates(0) (so using column index)

.Value=dates.columns(0) (again using column index)

I've also tried declaring variables, and setting their values to the values in the columns, but the code returns an error saying that "Value of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' cannot be converted to string".

I should point out that i'm doing this for 3 tables at once in this sub, 2 of them will only have a single row of data, but the third has an indeterminate number of rows.

I'm afraid I don't know what else to do.  I'm lead to believe by my mate and my lecturer that this should work, and of course it will work, but the evidence says otherwise.

if I'm going about this entirely the wrong way, could someone please enlighten me as to what i SHOULD be doing?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
dates.Columns("AcademicYear")
```

Is a *whole* column. You can only assign the value from one **row**.

For example, to use the first row of the DataTable:

```
.Parameters("@AcademicYear").Value = dates.Rows[0]("AcademicYear")
```

Comment: I'm actually doing this with 3 tables at once, but they each suffer the same problem, i guess i should have mentioned that in my question.
2 of them will only have one row anyway, but the third has an indeterminant number of rows in it, so how would i deal with that situation?

Comment: @Archaon6044 - It doesn't matter that they have one row or not. You still need to access a row at a time (a you can access a row from each table).

Comment: oh that's not what i meant, in fact numbering the rows has already fixed the problem with the first two tables, but i don't see how to apply it to the third table, where i don't now how many rows there are (this table gets data from input into a data grid view)

i thought i could use a For Each loop for this, but it returns the same error about failed type conversion
the code i'm using for my loop is

`For Each drPupilItem As DataRow In pupils.Rows
     .Parameters("@Class").Value = pupils.Columns("Class")`

Comment: Again, you go with the columns: `pupils.Columns("Class")`. You now have a reference to the row, so use it: `drPupilItem["Class"]`.

Comment: god i feel so stupid :P  cheers for all your help mate it's all working right now.  thanks a bunch